# 'can not connect to the service chromedriver' error is occured on linux ubuntu

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver, ubuntu-22.04

I am facing issues with Selenium.
The code runs fine in the Windows environment, but encounters an error in the Linux Ubuntu environment.

This is what the installed versions look like:
Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Python 3.9.18
Selenium 4.16.0
Chrome 120.0.6099.224
Chromedriver 120.0.6099.109

This is the code:

```
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
from selenium import webdriver as wd
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

request_url = 'https://www.stories.com/kr_krw/whats-new/all.html#/ctgr-filter=192013/sort-filter=disp_prty'

ua = UserAgent()
user_agent = ua.chrome

options = wd.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument(f'user-agent={user_agent}')
options.add_argument('--window-size= 1920, 1080')
options.add_argument('incognito')
options.add_argument('--headless')

service = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver = wd.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
driver.get(request_url)
```

And it shows the below error:

`Can not connect to the Service /home/.wdm/drivers/chromedriver/linux64/120.0.6099.109/chromedriver-linux64/chromedriver`

The installed versions are the same on both Windows and Linux Ubuntu.
The Selenium 4.16.0 version change log says it supports Chrome 120.
The ChromeDriver is installed in the correct location, and the permissions are set to 755, making it executable.
I suspected a compatibility issue with the ChromeDriver, so I separately installed chromedriver version 119.0.6045.105 and tried running it, but encountered the same error.

Comment: If you are using compatible ChromeDriver version, there might be an issue with the path. Ensure that the path is correct.

Comment: @TheHungryCub The path is accurate because the library itself specifies and executes the path. Just in case, I downloaded it separately and tried to specify the path, but it failed.

Answer (score -1):

That most likely is related to the path or version of the chromedriver. Make sure that the path and driver version matches the Google Chrome Driver installed on your system.

As a second approach, Where you are not required to pass the chromedriver path, I recommend using **seleniumbase** (More Info here: https://seleniumbase.io/)

Here is a sample code:

```
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
from seleniumbase import BaseCase
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

class MyTestClass(BaseCase):

    def test_stories_website(self):
        request_url = 'https://www.stories.com/kr_krw/whats-new/all.html#/ctgr-filter=192013/sort-filter=disp_prty'

        ua = UserAgent()
        user_agent = ua.chrome

        options = self.chrome_options()
        options.add_argument(f'user-agent={user_agent}')
        options.add_argument('--window-size=1920,1080')
        options.add_argument('incognito')
        options.add_argument('--headless')

        # Set the path to ChromeDriverManager in your system
        path = ChromeDriverManager().install()
        self.driver = self.create_webdriver(path=path, options=options)

        self.open(request_url)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyTestClass().test_stories_website()
```

Comment: I tried seleniumbase, but it have same error. 
`from seleniumbase import Driver    
driver = Driver(browser="chrome", headless=True, incognito = True)    
driver.get(request_url)`      
**Can not connect to the Service /usr/bin/chromedriver**
And The path is accurate because the library itself specifies and executes the path. Just in case, I downloaded it separately and tried to specify the path, but it failed.